# OpenVPN 2.4.7 and Windows 8.1 = complete halt and disconnects

Tags: windows, ethernet, openvpn

I run Windows 8.1 Pro and OpenVPN 2.4.7 on a laptop with built-in NVidia chipset (nForce Ethernet Controller).

Without VPN everything is working well.

But if VPN is up and I begin downloading a file or video, after 1-2 minutes, it comes to a complete halt, timeouts, and disconnects.

It's easy to reproduce: I open 2 console windows, one with "ping 1.1.1.1 -t" and another with "youtube-dl".
As soon as the video download runs for 30...40....50 seconds, the pings start to timeout. After a while, the OpenVPN GUi tray icon goes from green to yellow.
Sometimes it even can't reconnect the session and I have to manually Disable/Enable the adapter.

It feels like it gets clogged and is overwhelmed / suffocating by the incoming traffic...

With low traffic (pings or lightweight browsing the web) it can live for hours ...

What I have ruled out so far:

1. My ISP does not throttle the connection.
   Linux/Raspberry seems to work fine with the same OpenVPN profile and provider.
2. It's unique to my current Windows 8.1 setup. I had used Windows 2003 on this hardware without any problem.

So I could speculate that something is either messed up in Windows 8.1 (Winsock, IP stack), a buggy driver for the Ethernet, or something it wrong with OpenVPN itself or TAP driver.

Has anyone got any idea what it might be? Thanks!

Comment: The VPN provider is also a factor. Which is it?

Comment: No, the same .ovpn profile works perfectly on Linux, WinXP, Win2003. Haven't tried 7 or 10, but I think it would be just as buggy as 8.1

Besides, like I said, when connection halts and I press Disconnect in OpenVPN GUI - both "Disconnect" and "Reconnect" buttons go grey (and stuck) and I have to respawn the adapter (in Control Panel - Network - Adapter settings).